# ExtJs - How to trigger the update event on a store manually?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

How to fire the `update` event on a store manually, by clicking a button or a link?

I'm trying this:

```
var someStore = Ext.getCmp('someGrid').getStore();
//Save yes is a hyperlink I inserted in the DOM.

Ext.get('save-yes').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    someStore.fireEvent('update');
});

someStore.on('update', function(){
    console.log('Updating');    
});
```

The click works, but the store's event is not triggered.

Comment: It should work.Can you post running code at https://fiddle.sencha.com ?

Comment: I'll try to, since it's a big code!

Comment: It does work. See https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/75m Make sure you add a `console.log` to your click handler to make sure your click handler is working

Comment: Yes!I'm doing the same thing. Console.log works when I click the hyperlink. I have added the hyperlink using the `DomHelper` class. Actually I'm trying to code a confirmation when someone edits the row of a property grid!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but what I posted proves that it does work, the problem is somewhere else, not in the code you've posted. You have to shrink your code until you find the problem, best way is by isolating parts in that fiddle like I did.

Comment: I get this error as well: `TypeError: a is undefined`. The click works fine, the store object too is right.

Comment: I can't help if you don't address the questions I'm posing. How am I supposed to guess what `a` is? You have to show code that uses `a`. Even better, do what I did, create a reduction of the problem

Comment: Okay... I'll create a fiddle of whatever I'm trying!

Answer (score 1):

Never fire events this way. The library events are fired when something happens that needs to be handled so firing update event when data has not changed does not make any sense. Event listener is expected to handle changes so it does not need to run when there is no change.

Further, events must be fired with some signature so you need to grab data that original fireEvent uses that can be problematic very often.

Last, but probably most important, once you have a function that serves as the listener you do not need to artificially fire the event for the function to run. You can just call the function.

Comment: I was going to mention that, but I just answered the question.

Comment: True! I'm trying to make a confirmation box when the data in a property grid is changed. I've managed to build the box, but I'm not able to trigger the save when the button is clicked.

Comment: If you cannot trigger it, you won't be able to trigger it by firing the event. If you call `store.sync()` and store does not save the changed data it won't save the data if you fire update event.

Comment: For stores I find useful to fire `load` events. Sometimes I have to wait 1 or more stores are completely loaded, and instead write a ton of code to manage every situation, I write a nested onloads. After that, for each store I check if it's already loaded. If it is, I manually fire the `load` event for each store. This should be better handled with Deferreds, but it works anyway.

Comment: Yes, firing events that way may work, however, it's a very bad practice anyway.